# How to consume this API in Python? I just can't

Tags: python, api, request

So i'm trying to consume this API, I got this URL http://www.ventamovil.com.mx:9092/service.asmx?op=Check_Balance

There you can write this {"User":"6144135400","Password":"Prueba$$"} on the input field and you get a response.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTEii.png

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQAZ.png)

But when i try to consume this api on python i just can't, i don't exactly know how to consume correctly:

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsvKL.png)

As you can see i got a different response with my code, i should be getting the same response as the "Response" image.

Comment: don't post code as images

Comment: @dldamian Please edit your question and paste the code directly instead of links to images.

Comment: Is that a real user/password??

Comment: @Yatin thanks, as i'm new here i'm still learning how post a question correctly :)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille No, they are user/password for testing only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save yourself some time, you can use their request to build python code automatically, all you have to do is:

- Just as you did at first, enter the json in the input field and invoke.
- open the network tab, copy the post request they made as curl

```sh
curl 'http://www.ventamovil.com.mx:9092/service.asmx/Check_Balance' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36' -H 'Origin: http://www.ventamovil.com.mx:9092' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'Referer: http://www.ventamovil.com.mx:9092/service.asmx?op=Check_Balance' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7' --data 'jrquest=%7B%22User%22%3A6144135400%2C+%22Password%22%3A+%22Prueba%24%24%22%7D' --compressed --insecure
```

- Go to postman and import the curl, then click code and select python, and here you go you have all the right headers needed

```py
import requests

url = "http://www.ventamovil.com.mx:9092/service.asmx/Check_Balance"

payload = 'jrquest=%7B%22User%22%3A6144135400%2C+%22Password%22%3A+%22Prueba%24%24%22%7D'
headers = {
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

As you can see, they accept their input as form encoded payload.

You need to modify this request to be parameterized with user/password you want each time you use.

Btw, the output of this python code is:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<string xmlns="http://www.ventamovil.com.mx/ws/">{"Confirmation":"00","Saldo_Inicial":"10000","Compras":"9360","Ventas":"8416","Comision":"469","Balance":"10345.92"}</string>'
```

Comment: Thanks @kareem_emad you help me a lot :D